# Variable Range as Input

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am a new user of VBA for Excel (2013), and I've been struggling with a problem for quite a while.

I want to create a function that, among the other input variables that the user has to provide, has several ranges of cells, that should be variable and "easily selectable" by the user themselves.
It should be something like (for example) the Excel "SUM" formula, where you can input several ranges such as "A1:C1,F1:H1,...", selecting them with your mouse.

Moreover, I have to transfer the values selected by the user in a 2D array. Every range selected by the user has to become a row of my 2D array.

Further to what I've said so far, the number of ranges that the user inputs should be anyone, and only the first one should be mandatory.

Given the "structure" of my spreadsheet, all the data that the user has to select are arranged in rows. (Does it make any difference if they are arranged in rows or in columns?)

Please note that I shouldn't use the "Input Box", because it slows down a lot the procedure when I "drag down" a row to apply the formula to many rows below the active one.

Below, I report the only parts of the code that I was able to write (not very much...)

```
Function Trial_Version(MyRange1 As Range, MyRange2 As Range, MyRange3 As Range) As Double
''' The number of ranges that the user is be able to input
'''should be anyone. Only the first Range should be mandatory

    Dim TotalArray()() As Double

'''The user should be able to input as many "sub-arrays" as they want,
'''so I do not know how many parentheses to write

    TotalArray = (MyRange1)(MyRange2)

'''here, the same problem as the previous line

    RANGE_TO_ARRAY = TotalArray
'''This is the output of my function

End Function
```

Thank you very much in advance,
Orlando

Answer (score 1):

Not the full answer, but hopefully points you in the right direction.

- A standard Range object can already hold multiple 'areas' (e.g. C5:D9,G9:H16,B14:D18). You can loop through these using the .Areas property.
- You can get easily get a 2D array of values from a Range object by using a Variant variable (e.g. Dim a as Variant, a = SomeRange). If multiple areas are selected however, this method will only get the first area, so you'll need to loop through each area to get all values.
- The code below requires validation added, plus possibly handling any column / row offsets (i.e. See comment in loop related to indexes).

```
Public Function ProcessRange(ByRef rng As Range)
```

`'# PURPOSE: Process multi-area range

  Dim rngArea As Range ' Single area in multi-area selection
  Dim lngCol As Long ' Column in selected range(area), 1 based
  Dim lngRow As Long ' Row in selected range(area), 1 based
  Dim avarValues As Variant ' 2D variant array for range(area) values, 1 based


  ' --> Add validation here <--


  ' Go through each area in selected range
  ' --------------------------------------
  For Each rngArea In rng.Areas

    ' Store the values into 2d array (Row, Column),  1 based
    avarValues = rngArea

    ' Show each value held in the array
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(avarValues, 1)
      For lngCol = 1 To UBound(avarValues, 2)
        ' Note row / column index is NOT necessarily the same as the row/column on the worksheet
        ' Index 1 will be the first cell in the selected area
        Debug.Print "Area " + rngArea.Address + ", value in AREA row " & lngRow & ", column " & lngCol & ": " & avarValues(lngRow, lngCol)
      Next lngCol
    Next lngRow
  Next rng

End Function`

Comment: Thanks @kernel!

I used ParamArray command, to insert different Ranges.

Then, to understand if all the data were stored, I made a function that gets these data and gives you them back in an array.
the code is:

`Function EXAMPLE(ParamArray UserInput() As Variant) As Variant`

`EXAMPLE = UserInput()`

`End Function`

The function gives me back only the first group of data input (e.g. the first range input).
If I type, at the end,  `UserInput(3)`, it gives me back the third range, and so on.
It is like the data are "taken", but it hides them in someway....

Comment: Well, I've just discovered that the data were stored in a 2D Array. In fact, if I select an area of the right sizes (columns and rows), and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, it gives me all the values.
I thought that the array I had created were 1D (an array of arrays), and I don't know how it became 2D...

Comment: If you assign a Range variable to a Variant variable, the Variant becomes a 2D array containing the values in the Range. In your example, the function is taking a Range (or several) as a parameter, but you have your UserInput() as a Variant, so the UserInput() become a 2D array.

Comment: Thank you very much @kernel! After some trials and "exploring" the results, I "discovered" this thing as well. This is pretty good for me, because I can pick the values I want from `UserInput()`, as soon as I know precisely how they are allocated in the array. Thank you very much again for your help!!